# academicons in overleaf

Tags: packages

Holy Dina I have tried so many different resume templates in overleaf and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use academicons in any of them. I have seen a few similar questions but with no answers that work for me. It says in the package information "This package requires either the XƎ(LA)TEX or Lua(LA)TEX engine to load the Academicons font from the system, which requires installing the bundled academicons.ttf font file" but I have literally 0 idea how to actually do that. This is just template code that I added \usepackage{academicons} to which clearly doesn't work. Help!

```
\geometry{left=2cm,right=10cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}
\ifxetexorluatex
  \setmainfont{Carlito}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi
\definecolor{VividPurple}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\colorlet{heading}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{accent}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage{academicons}

\begin{document}
\name{BECKY}
\tagline{}
\personalinfo{
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
  \faEnvelope{email}
  \phone{}
  \faWhatsapp{}
  \linkedin{Becky F}
  \faInstagram{becky.outside}
  \aiResearchGate{Becky F}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to change the overleaf compiler from pdflatex to xelatex in Menu > Settings > Compiler, then I got some extra lines of code from github including  `\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}` and then `\usepackage{academicons}` and it worked :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on those "extra lines of codes"? I switched the compiler to xelatex but it still won't work. I don't even know why... if I try to `\usepackage{academicons}` it messes up the whole pdf...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what my problem was: I'd been having the same trouble despite having used xetex from the getgo—a handful of the icons (e.g., PsyArXiv, SSRN) only render correctly when you switch to the newest TeX live version, 2021. You'll see this as an option when you click the menu button at the very top left.

This is the only thing I would add to Becky's answer—I added no further lines from GitHub.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).